# R: inconsistent behaviour when adding numbers in matrices

Tags: r, matrix, addition, cbind

I am trying to solve an exercise on Fibonacci sequences in R. The crux is that the animals are mortal.
Goal is to enter 3 variables (life span, overall duration, number of offspring). The animals need 1 time unit to mature. To solve this, I create a matrix with a timer in the first row, the number of couples of offspring in the second row, then the mature couples, then the sum of offspring and mature couples. I take into account the mortality by substracting from the mature animals the number of animals that were born "i" months ago (i = life span)

```
vec <- vector()

wabbits3 <- function(i,k,l) {
  wabbits3_chabo(i,k,l,1,0, vec, 1, i)
}

wabbits3_chabo <- function(i,k,l,m,n,t,o,p){
  if (k == 0) {print(t)}
  else if (p == 1) {wabbits3_chabo(i, (k-1), l,
                   ((n+m-(t[2,(ncol(t)-i+1)]))*l),
                   (n+m-(t[2,(ncol(t)-i+1)])),
                   cbind(t, c((o),
                              (m),
                              (n),
                              (m+n))),
                   (o+1),
                   1)}
  else {wabbits3_chabo(i, (k-1), l,
                   (n*l),
                   (n+m),
                   cbind(t, c((o),
                              (m),
                              (n),
                              (m+n))),
                   (o+1),
                   (p-1))}
}
```

Now, to the actual question: if I test the numbers: `wabbits3(365, 6, 1)`, it never enters the else if branch as it never reaches p = 1, and everything works fine. 
But, when choosing smaller numbers `(wabbits3(3, 6, 1)`), it enters the else `if` branch, and the addition "`(m+n)`" doesnt work anymore. 
The `cbind` command is exactly the same in the "`if`" and "e`lse if`" branch, so why doesnt it work both times?

Result of `wabbits3(365, 6, 1)`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    1    0    1    1    2    3
[3,]    0    1    1    2    3    5
[4,]    1    1    2    3    5    8
```

(the sum of the second and third row, displayed in the fourth row works)

Result of `wabbits3(3, 6, 1)`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
 [2,]    1    0    1    4    5    6
 [3,]    0    1    1    4    5    6
 [4,]    1    1    2    4    5    6
```

(the addition of the second and third row doesnt work anymore, once it enters the `else if` branch(in the fourth column))

Is my issue understandable? Anything unclear?
Thanks in advance!

PS.: I am sure that there are others mistakes in my code, but I´d prefer finding those myself. Right now I´m simply baffled why sth as simple as an addition isnt working...

EDIT: Turns out that simply using rbind (in both branches of course) seems to fix the issue... But why?!